# XSLT nested list grouping wrong

Tags: xml, list, xslt, nested, grouping

My XSLT is grouping my nested list together the wrong way. Desired output below. It is grouping all hanging_indents as in both ref-list. Please help. I have mostly code below.I have mostly code below.I have mostly code below.

### Input XML 1st scenario:

```
<document>
  <head1>Heading 1</head1>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>
  <head1>Heading 2</head1>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>

   <head1>Bibliography</head1>
        <bib_head>Books</bib_head>
            <hanging_indent>book citation 1</hanging_indent>
            <hanging_indent>book citation 2</hanging_indent>
        <bib_head>Periodicals</bib_head>
            <hanging_indent>per citation 1</hanging_indent>
            <hanging_indent>per citation 2</hanging_indent>
</document>
```

### Input XML 2nd scenario (no bib_heads):

```
<document>
  <head1>Heading 1</head1>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>
  <head1>Heading 2</head1>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>

   <head1>Bibliography</head1>
            <hanging_indent>book citation 1</hanging_indent>
            <hanging_indent>book citation 2</hanging_indent>
            <hanging_indent>per citation 1</hanging_indent>
            <hanging_indent>per citation 2</hanging_indent>
</document>
```

### My XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="head1">        
    <xsl:variable name="head1" select="." />

<xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*[1])='body_text'">
        <sec sec-type="bodytext" indexed="true">
            <title><xsl:value-of select="."/></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::body_text[preceding-sibling::head1[1] = $head1]" />
        </sec>
    </xsl:if>


  <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*[1])='hanging_indent'">
        <sec sec-type="hangindent" indexed="true">
            <title><xsl:value-of select="."/></title>
            <ref-list>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::hanging_indent[preceding-sibling::head1[1] = $head1]" />
            </ref-list>
        </sec>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*[1])='bib_head'">
        <sec sec-type="hangindent" indexed="true">
            <title><xsl:value-of select="."/></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::bib_head"/>
        </sec>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template><xsl:template match="hanging_indent">
    <ref>
        <citation>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </citation>
    </ref>
</xsl:template><xsl:template match="bib_head">
    <ref-list>
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::hanging_indent"/>
    </ref-list>
</xsl:template>
```

### Desired XML output structure:

```
<sec sec-type="bodytext" indexed="true">
  <title>Heading 1</title>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>
</sec>
<sec sec-type="bodytext" indexed="true">
  <title>Heading 2</title>
  <body_text>foo text</body_text>
</sec>
<sec sec-type="hangindent" indexed="true">
  <title>Bibliography</title>
  <ref-list>
    <title>Books</title>
    <ref><citation>book citation 1</citation></ref>
    <ref><citation>book citation 2</citation></ref>
  </ref-list>
  <ref-list>
    <title>Periodicals</title>
    <ref><citation>per citation 1</citation></ref>
    <ref><citation>per citation 2</citation></ref>
  </ref-list>
</sec>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try:

- Grouping the `hanging_indent` elements by the generated id of the first preceding sibling `bib_head`.
- Grouping the `bib_head` elements by the generated id of the first preceding sibling `head1`.
- Grouping the `body_text` elements by the generated id of the first preceding sibling `head1`.
- Grouping the `hanging_indent` elements by the generated id of the first preceding sibling `head1`. (Used if there are no `bib_head` elements.)

**Scenario #1 XML Input** (indent changed to lessen confusion about nesting)

```
<document>
    <head1>Heading 1</head1>
    <body_text>foo text</body_text>
    <body_text>foo text</body_text>
    <head1>Heading 2</head1>
    <body_text>foo text</body_text>
    <head1>Bibliography</head1>
    <bib_head>Books</bib_head>
    <hanging_indent>book citation 1</hanging_indent>
    <hanging_indent>book citation 2</hanging_indent>
    <bib_head>Periodicals</bib_head>
    <hanging_indent>per citation 1</hanging_indent>
    <hanging_indent>per citation 2</hanging_indent>
</document>
```

**Scenario #2 XML Input (no bib_head)** (indent changed to lessen confusion about nesting)

```
<document>
    <head1>Heading 1</head1>
    <body_text>foo text</body_text>
    <body_text>foo text</body_text>
    <head1>Heading 2</head1>
    <body_text>foo text</body_text>
    <head1>Bibliography</head1>
    <hanging_indent>book citation 1</hanging_indent>
    <hanging_indent>book citation 2</hanging_indent>
    <hanging_indent>per citation 1</hanging_indent>
    <hanging_indent>per citation 2</hanging_indent>
</document>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Group hanging_indent by first preceding sibling bib_head.-->
  <xsl:key name="hi-by-bh" 
    match="hanging_indent" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::bib_head[1])"/>
  <!--Group bib_head by first preceding head1.-->
  <xsl:key name="bh-by-h1" 
    match="bib_head" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::head1[1])"/>
  <!--Group body_text by first preceding head1.-->
  <xsl:key name="bt-by-h1" 
    match="body_text" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::head1[1])"/>
  <!--Group hanging_indent by first preceding head1.-->
  <xsl:key name="hi-by-h1" 
    match="hanging_indent" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::head1[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="head1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="head1[following-sibling::*[1][self::body_text]]">
    <sec sec-type="bodytext" indexed="true">
      <title><xsl:value-of select="."/></title>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bt-by-h1',generate-id())"/>
    </sec>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="head1[following-sibling::*[1][self::bib_head]]">
    <sec sec-type="hangindent" indexed="true">
      <title><xsl:value-of select="."/></title>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bh-by-h1',generate-id())"/>
    </sec>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="head1[following-sibling::*[1][self::hanging_indent]]">
    <sec sec-type="hangindent" indexed="true">
      <title><xsl:value-of select="."/></title>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('hi-by-h1',generate-id())"/>
    </sec>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bib_head">
    <ref-list>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="."/></title>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('hi-by-bh',generate-id())"/>
    </ref-list>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hanging_indent">
    <ref><citation><xsl:value-of select="."/></citation></ref>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body_text">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output Scenario #1**

```
<sec sec-type="bodytext" indexed="true">
   <title>Heading 1</title>
   <body_text>foo text</body_text>
   <body_text>foo text</body_text>
</sec>
<sec sec-type="bodytext" indexed="true">
   <title>Heading 2</title>
   <body_text>foo text</body_text>
</sec>
<sec sec-type="hangindent" indexed="true">
   <title>Bibliography</title>
   <ref-list>
      <title>Books</title>
      <ref>
         <citation>book citation 1</citation>
      </ref>
      <ref>
         <citation>book citation 2</citation>
      </ref>
   </ref-list>
   <ref-list>
      <title>Periodicals</title>
      <ref>
         <citation>per citation 1</citation>
      </ref>
      <ref>
         <citation>per citation 2</citation>
      </ref>
   </ref-list>
</sec>
```

**Output Scenario #2**

```
<sec sec-type="bodytext" indexed="true">
   <title>Heading 1</title>
   <body_text>foo text</body_text>
   <body_text>foo text</body_text>
</sec>
<sec sec-type="bodytext" indexed="true">
   <title>Heading 2</title>
   <body_text>foo text</body_text>
</sec>
<sec sec-type="hangindent" indexed="true">
   <title>Bibliography</title>
   <ref>
      <citation>book citation 1</citation>
   </ref>
   <ref>
      <citation>book citation 2</citation>
   </ref>
   <ref>
      <citation>per citation 1</citation>
   </ref>
   <ref>
      <citation>per citation 2</citation>
   </ref>
</sec>
```

Comment: I've updated my input (2nd scenario) to show the second kind of input. When I run it on that scenario, all I get returned is <head1>Bibliography</head1>

Comment: Great Thanks. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify the XSLT version, I choose version 2.0,
which provides an easy and natural way of grouping elements.

The task boils down to 2 embedded `for-each-group` loops.
The external loop creates each group starting from `head1` element
and the inner loop starting from `bib_head`.

Here is the script you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="head1">
      <xsl:variable name="type">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-group()[2][name()='body_text']">
            <xsl:text>bodytext</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>hangindent</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="group" select="current-group()"/>
      <xsl:element name="sec">
        <xsl:attribute name="sec-type" select="$type"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="indexed" select="'true'"/>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="$group[name()='head1']"/>
        </title>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$type='bodytext'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$group[name()='body_text']"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="BibHead">
              <xsl:with-param name="group" select="subsequence($group, 2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Generate ref-list elements -->
  <!-- group - source group without head1 -->
  <xsl:template name="BibHead">
    <xsl:param name="group"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$group" group-starting-with="bib_head">
      <ref-list>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[name()='bib_head']"/></title>
        <xsl:for-each select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)">
          <ref><citation><xsl:value-of select="."/></citation></ref>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ref-list>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not using XSLT 2.0 or 3.0. I can't use xsl:for-each-group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 you could simply nest two `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with` so with Saxon 9.8 or current Altova you could use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="STREAMABLE" static="yes" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>

    <xsl:mode _streamable="{$STREAMABLE}" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="head1">
                <sec sec-type="body-text" indexed="true">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="bib_head">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="self::bib_head">
                                <ref-list>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                                </ref-list>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </sec>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="head1 | bib_head">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="hanging_indent">
        <ref>
            <citation>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </citation>
        </ref>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2.0 simply remove the

```
    <xsl:param name="STREAMABLE" static="yes" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>
```

and replace

```
    <xsl:mode _streamable="{$STREAMABLE}" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not using  XSLT 2.0 or 3.0. I can't use xsl:for-each-group.